# Why AOP does not work in my Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I tried to add AspectJ to one of my Spring Boot projects but failed. I tried to create very simple Spring Boot project but it doesn't work too. I've add @EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation etc. but get still the same. What am I doing wrong?

This is code of this simple project:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@Aspect
@Component
public class MessageAspect {   

    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.MessageController.mainMethod())")
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println("before method");
    }   

}


@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String mainMethod() {
        return "result from mainMethod";
    }

}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: try adding two `..` inside mainMethod() like so: `com.example.demo.MessageController.mainMethod(..)` and then see if it works.

Comment: also, try declaring the aspect class as a bean in your spring config and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are what I think help you :

- you forgot to add a bean of your aspect class:

> ```
> @Bean MessageAspect messageAspect() {  
>   return new MessageAspect();
> }
> ```

- use `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` without `(proxyTargetClass = true)`
- be sure your `@Aspect`  annotation is scaned. you can use  `@ComponentScan("myAspectPackageContainer.*")`
- you don't need `@Component` annotation when use `@Aspect` anymore.
- use method modifier in your expression  `"execution( public * com.example.demo..."`
- at the end of your expression use `"myPackage.*.*(..)"`
- check with these two dependencies :

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
>     <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
>     <version>1.8.7</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
>     <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
>     <version>1.8.7</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

By the way you can use `@ControllerAdvice` if you need to just aspect your controller classes

Comment: My aspect class wasn't autowired as a bean. The problem was in the file extension. I've created it as Aspect with .aj extension and forgot about it (IDEA hides extensions). When I've changed extension to .java everything started to work fine.

Comment: @V. Perfilev  YOU SAVED MY DAY

Answer (score 0):

Your comment in the accepted answer saved me, so I figured it's best to add it as an answer for others:

I'd used IntelliJ's "Create Aspect" which created a file with extension `.aj`.  I couldn't understand why other classes couldn't see my new Aspect class, even though IntelliJ was auto-completing it.  IntelliJ hides file extensions and the icon was the same as a class, so it wasn't obvious.

Renaming the file to `.java` in the IntelliJ project manager fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

removing `@Component` annotation helped me in this case.